# React - Table tr and td click events

Tags: reactjs, html-table

I have a table component with click events on the rows and data cells but only the event of the row gets triggered. Is there a "React" way of making sure the cell click event will be triggered?

EDIT - Here is a code example

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Header item</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {this.state.filteredGiftCards &&
      this.state.filteredGiftCards.map(item => (
        <tr onClick={() => this.onClick}>
          <td>
            <Button className={styles.btn} onClick={this.onDelete}>
              <Delete className={styles.icon} />
            </Button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Share a code snippet so that i can help you.

Comment: Can you please share the whole component code? We cannot help you without "full picture".

Comment: Or, it would be much better, if you will share the code snippet with the reproduction of the problem

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance the problem is that only the tr's onClick gets triggered instead of the td's Button onClick